# Bash sha256 not matching erlang one

Tags: cryptography, erlang, elixir, sha256, erlang-otp

Erlang returns me a different result than the bash command when I "sha256".

```
echo a | sha256sum, returns: 87428fc522803d31065e7bce3cf03fe475096631e5e07bbd7a0fde60c4cf25c7  -
```

Erlang

```
    Bin = crypto:hash(sha256, "a").


<<202,151,129,18,202,27,189,202,250,194,49,179,154,35,220,
      77,167,134,239,248,20,124,78,114,185,128,119,133,175,
      238,72,187>>
```

I tried different bin to hex from [bin to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768197/erlang-ioformatting-a-binary-to-hex)
None of them gave the result I was expecting.

I got this as a result:

```
    bin_to_hex:bin_to_hex(Bin).
<<"CA978112CA1BBDCAFAC231B39A23DC4DA786EFF8147C4E72B9807785AFEE48BB">>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `echo a` will include a newline. When I add a newline to the erlang version, I get the expected hash:

```erlang
1> Bin = crypto:hash(sha256, "a\n").
<<135,66,143,197,34,128,61,49,6,94,123,206,60,240,63,228,
  117,9,102,49,229,224,123,189,122,15,222,96,196,...>>
2> binary:encode_hex(Bin).
<<"87428FC522803D31065E7BCE3CF03FE475096631E5E07BBD7A0FDE60C4CF25C7">>
```

You can also tell `echo` not to use a newline with `-n`:

```sh
$ echo -n a | sha256sum
ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb  -
```